# Separate textbox value and add to list

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to take numbers that are added to a textbox and on button click add the numbers to my List, for instance a user can input:

> 123456

So this would become:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3 etc

I'm not sure how to separate each digit and add it to the list?

```
        List<int> integerList = new List<int>();

        try
        {
            int number = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);                
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                integerList.Add(number);
                listBox1.Items.Add(number);
            }
```

Comment: how about : `1234asdas56`, what's your expected result?

Comment: @CuongLe Regular expression protects the input

Comment: Do you want to have a list containing each separate digit in the textbox text or do you want a list of digits from zero until the value of the textbox?

Comment: I want a list of each seperate digit in the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *indexer* to get the characters of string.

```
try
{          
    for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
    {
         integerList.Add(int.Parse(textBox1.Text[i].ToString());
         listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text[i]);
    }
 }
```

You can use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) as well.

```
List<int> integerList = new List<int>();
textBox1.Text.Select(c=>Convert.ToInt32(c).ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: Check my updated answer, I have converted the character to string.

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = textBox1.Text.Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString()))
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        List<int> integerList = new List<int>();

        foreach(char c in textBox1.Text)
        {
          int x = int.Parse(c.ToString());
          integerList.Add(x);
          listBox1.Items.Add(x);
        }
```

or is it this that you want to do:

```
   List<int> integerList = new List<int>();
   for(int i = 0; i < int.Parse(textBox1.Text); i++)
   {
      integerList.Add(i);
      listBox1.Items.Add(i);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

so use this code :

```
 List<int> integerList = new List<int>();

 foreach (char c in textBox1.Text)
  {
   var d = int.Parse(c.ToString());
   integerList.Add(d);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); 
List<int> integerList = new List<int>();

x = Math.Abs(x);
while (x >= 1)
{
     integerList.Add(x % 10);
     x = x / 10;
}
integerList.Reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this one, it works I teted it :

```
        foreach (char n in textBox1.Text)
        {
            int number = int.Parse(n.ToString());
            listBox1.Items.Add(number);
        }
```